Tax filing in Argentina, Uruguay and Paraguay
Relative to USA and India, how easy or difficult is it to file local and federal tax returns in Argentina, Uruguay and Paraguay, as a tax resident? (Income expected just from capital gains and farming.)
Reason for the question - I'm an Indian who's lived in USA (tax resident) - so those are my reference points.
And I am considering moving to one of these countries as a farmer - and I dread the chore of filing taxes.
For companies -


Running a farm these days means running it like a business. And that means having a good tax professional to do all the stuff they know how to do while you do the farming stuff.

I understand the desire to keep things simple, but this is omitting the (financially much more significant) question of which tax rates are higher. Without knowing these countries in particular, I would say it's pretty difficult to have a more administratively cumbersome tax administration system than the US.

Also - I would consider the difficulty of filing taxes less-than-trivial, compared with the actual difficulty of farming. Even if you are already a farmer, surely there is a greater difficulty in farming a completely new climate and country, vs filing taxes (something that even if you paid a professional to do it, is a trivial business expense when compared with farming, which is notoriously capital-intensive).
